# EJB @Asynchronous - Transaction is not active after few minutes executing

Tags: java, asynchronous, transactions, jboss, ejb

I've a async method in my singleton session bean, which after a few minutes executing, is thrown the following exception after finalize a method of another transaction:

**Caused by: org.jboss.util.NestedSQLException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff0afd40ba:126a:4f50fff5:42 status: ActionStatus.ABORTED**

I've tried add this anotation - @TransactionTimeout - but does not works.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: The spec does not cover transaction timeouts.  Tagged it as 'jboss' in hopes someone more familiar with that platform can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Configuring default timeout in transaction-jboss-beans.xml :

`<attribute name="TransactionTimeout">100</attribute>`

2.Using BMT to set the timeout for a transaction manually :

`userTransaction.setTransactionTimeout(100);`

3.Overriding at method-level for a session bean in xml definition :

```
//--
    <method-attributes> 
       <method> 
         <method-name>someMethod</method-name> 
           <transaction-timeout>100</transaction-timeout> 
       </method> 
    </method-attributes>
//--
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the annotation `@TransactionTimeout` if you do not want to adjust the standard timeout, there is the option to set the timeout for a transaction for a specific business method. For this purpose, JBoss / Wildfly has provided `@TransacationTimeout` annotation.

Before you start ensure you have already added the dependency to you project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.ejb3</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-ejb3-ext-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Important:**

The annotation only applies if it is specified at the point at which the transaction starts.

In your case, you start a new transaction with the asynchronous bean. So you have to do the configuration there too. In the following example, the method `foo` of bean`SomeBean` strikes after 5 minutes and method `lala` of `AsyncBean` after 10 minutes.

```
@Stateless
class SomeBean {

    @Inject
    AsyncBean asyncBean;

    @TransactionTimeout(value=5, unit= TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    public void foo() {
        asyncBean.lala()
    }
}
```

```
@Stateless
class AsyncBean {

    @Asynchronous
    @TransactionTimeout(value=10, unit= TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    public void lala() {
        ...
    }
}
```