# Set time out in EJB 2.x

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, ejb-2.x

I have been developing an EJB application(2.x) and 
I have to implement the set time out feature. Since I couldnt find any useful resource, kindly guide me how it can be done.

Appreciate for any input.

Comment: what do you mean with set time out feature?

Comment: @AccessTimeout(value = 20, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS) is it what you mean?

Comment: @GabrielAramburu: Time out the session once it pass the trigger time

Comment: @pshemek: I was wondering if there is any where in we can decide the time out feature of the application at one place

Comment: Can refer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/9553602/366964 might help.